# why my nifi can't split log into little part?

Tags: logging, apache-nifi, logback

there is question on nifi 1.6.

I try to split log into small part with logback, but logback config seem not work.

Here is my config.

```
    <appender name="APP_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.config.log.dir}/nifi-app.log</file>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">

            <fileNamePattern>${org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.config.log.dir}/daily/app_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>1MB</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>15</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <!--<immediateFlush>true</immediateFlush> -->
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{40} %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```

and here is stdout in cmd

```
12:43:19,838 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/D:/nifi-1.6.0-bin/nifi-1.6.0/conf/logback.xml]
12:43:19,893 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
12:43:19,899 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Will scan for changes in [file:/D:/nifi-1.6.0-bin/nifi-1.6.0/conf/logback.xml]
12:43:19,899 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Setting ReconfigureOnChangeTask scanning period to 30 seconds
12:43:19,901 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerContextListenerAction - Adding LoggerContextListener of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator] to the object stack
12:43:19,909 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@34ce8af7 - Propagating DEBUG level on Logger[ROOT] onto the JUL framework
12:43:19,909 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerContextListenerAction - Starting LoggerContextListener
12:43:19,909 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
12:43:19,912 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [APP_FILE]
12:43:19,953 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy@191382150 - No compression will be used
12:43:19,954 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy@191382150 - Will use the pattern D:/nifi-1.6.0-bin/nifi-1.6.0/bin/..//logs/daily/app_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log for the active file
12:43:19,956 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@880ec60 - The date pattern is 'yyyy-MM-dd' from file name pattern 'D:/nifi-1.6.0-bin/nifi-1.6.0/bin/..//logs/daily/app_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log'.
12:43:19,956 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@880ec60 - Roll-over at midnight.
12:43:19,958 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@880ec60 - Setting initial period to Thu Jan 07 12:42:43 CST 2021
12:43:19,959 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@880ec60 - SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP is deprecated. Use SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy instead
12:43:19,959 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@880ec60 - For more information see http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy
12:43:19,978 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[APP_FILE] - Active log file name: D:\nifi-1.6.0-bin\nifi-1.6.0\bin\..\\logs/nifi-app.log
12:43:19,978 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[APP_FILE] - File property is set to [D:\nifi-1.6.0-bin\nifi-1.6.0\bin\..\\logs/nifi-app.log]
```

in log directory, when app.log is bigger than 1MB,
**daily** directory is created, but no log file in there **daily**.

I wonder whether logback in nifi (or not for spring) can only split log by time?

same config in spring boot 2.x is working,in another words log can be split by size.

the logback version is 1.2.3.I try update  logback config by using **SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy**,same result i got.

):

Comment: `maxFileSize` and `%i` pattern do not belong to TimeBasedRollingPolicy

Comment: i change it to SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy but i do not work. it another nifi instance, logback is work. seem something not in logback.xml wrong